# npm doesn't start, nodejs-dev problems (ubuntu14)

Tags: linux, shell, node.js

I'm using ubuntu 14 and I installed nodejs-dev and nodejs and that's what appears me (photos below); can anyone help me to fix it? I really need it to continue with my project.

I read about create a link between nodejs and nodejs-dev or sth like that but I'm not a really good system guy.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Follow these steps to install nodejs on Ubuntu (which will also install npm)

For version 4:

`curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_4.x | sudo -E bash -`

For version 6:

`curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_6.x | sudo -E bash -`

Then:

`sudo apt-get install -y nodejs`

You may also want to install `build-essential` so you can install native addons from npm later on

`sudo apt-get install -y build-essential`

Source: [https://nodejs.org/en/download/package-manager/](http://sudo%20apt-get%20install%20-y%20build-essential)

Answer (score 0):

On Ubuntu, I prefer to install Node using NPM and n, which is a node version manager that you can get through NPM! It's very easy to get node like this (and you will probably want NPM anyway.) From the command line:

```
sudo apt-get install -y npm
sudo npm install -g n
sudo n lts
```

Before you do this, you may want to update apt:

```
sudo apt-get -y update
```